# Creating extra Buy now button on woocommerce product

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a new buy now sort of button besides the real buy now button on a woocommerce product. The function for this will be to be able to trade a product with another product, so when clicking this new buy now, it will open a custom popup, with image fields and the ability to add extra cash on top of the product - the seller will then be able to accept or deny the offer - how do i go about it? We use Woocommerce, Buddypress, And WooCommerce vendors - how can we do this?

After accepting it will go to checkout for buyer.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will create extra button on single product page beside add to cart button.

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button','additional_button');
    function additional_button(){
        echo '<input type="button" name="trade_product" value="Trade Product />"';
    }
```

Comment: We got that so far - but its more the technical of a pop up and let the traded product and the extra cash displayed on checkout, making it all smooth.

Comment: @mangnus pilegaard: above hook help you to add button beside add to card button. for your further requirement of pop up / trade product / add extra cash you have to add custom javascript, ajax, hook as well.

Comment: Okay - any idea on how to make it appear on checkout for the seller and buyer as reference?

Comment: there are multiple woo commerce hook for add value to cart like 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals','woocommerce_calculate_totals'.